# Implicit vs explicit "into"

Tags: rust

So I've noticed there are multiple ways to convert from `&str` to `String`, but (for the sake of my question) I'll only talk about two ways, which would be `"foo".to_string()` and `"foo".into()`.
Now I know that those are fundamentally different. The first of those is a method, while the second one is a trait-(implementation).

I currently need a piece of code that converts a `ObjectNode` into a `Node`.

First I implemented this using the `Into` trait:

```rust
struct ObjectNode {}

impl Into<Node> for ObjectNode {
    fn into(self) -> Node {
        Node::Object(self)
    }
}

enum Node {
    Object(ObjectNode)
}
```

But then I noticed that I had used `"foo".to_string()` instead of `"foo".into()` in my code. Simple because that's the thing I read online in pieces of code by other people. So I thought about implementing:

```rust
impl ObjectNode {
    fn into_node(self) -> Node {
        Node::Object(self)
    }
}
```

I'm now wondering if this "explicit" `into_node` method is somehow preferred over the "implicit" `into`, as `into` could be implemented for quiet a large number of types (which could lead to some... unexpected behavior, maybe?). Or maybe it's better to do it the other way around?

Comment: FWIW, [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) and [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) are *both* trait implementations.

Comment: Implementing the `Into<T>` trait on your types has an advantage over an arbitrary `.into_t()` method: you (or your users) can pass values of that type to any generic function that accepts an `impl Into<T>`. This is  more convenient than  functions taking a plain `T` and forcing an explicit conversion.

Comment: @Herohtar oh, thanks! For some reason I didn't bother to check, because it felt obvious to me it would be a method... Now I would like to re-phrase my question, but this was sort of the best example I could come up with.

Comment: Note from https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html: "One should avoid implementing Into and implement From instead. Implementing From automatically provides one with an implementation of Into thanks to the blanket implementation in the standard library."

Comment: @PitaJ yes I read that in a reddit thread, and I feared this would come up. I omitted a detail in the question, which is that I need access to members (`from: usize`, and `to: usize`) when doing the conversion. Those should be read only from the outside, and are thus private. - I could of course always implement a get method.

Comment: Private fields don't have anything to do with whether you implement `From` or `Into`, I think you are confused about something.

Comment: @trentᶠᵒʳᵐᵉʳˡʸᶜˡ mh, I would implement `impl From<ObjectNode> for Node`, and I assume `Node` doesn't have access to private fields of `ObjectNode`?

Comment: Private fields are accessible based on the module you're in, not based on the target type.

Comment: @PitaJ okay, interesting (totally unexpected though, coming from more object-oriented languages). So implement `From<ObjectNode> for Node` because of the greater flexibility when using generics?

Comment: Note that [`str::to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2444) and `str::into::<String>` both work by calling `String::from::<&str>` so they are completely equivalent.

Comment: FWIW, I avoid _both_ `.into()` and `.to_string()` and use `.to_owned()` simply because it reflects the intent better: I want to go from a shared `&str` to an owned `String`. `.to_string()` is used only because conversion to strings are very common (similar to why we have `FromString` and not using the usual `TryFrom`). So if a lot of types need to convert into `Node` (it is some "basic" type), then a custom trait makes sense; otherwise, use `From` and `Into`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess you should implement `From<ObjectNode>` for `Node` rather than implementing `Into<Node>`  for `ObjectNode` because the standard library for `Into` highlights it:-

> One should avoid implementing Into and implement
> From instead. Implementing From automatically
> provides one with an implementation of Into thanks to
> the blanket implementation in the standard library.

You should probably go for an implementation of `From` rather than creating a separate method for converting it. Most crates in the Rust ecosystem heavily depend on these functions for their type conversions.